# Does には in this sentence imply vagueness of the source?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に

This comes from a friend's post on Facebook. The situation is that my friend had injured his leg a while back, but it has since healed and he's now in for a checkup. His leg is in great condition, so the doctor thinks he's ready for sports.

> 先生{せんせい}には「もうフットサルして来{こ}い」と言{い}われた！

Which I think essentially means, "My doctor said [to me] I should go play futsal! (lit: play and come back)"

However, I thought `には` essentially meant "in the [place]". So, since my friend is not just using `に`, is he saying this was said by someone, maybe the doctor, maybe a nurse or someone, in the vicinity of the doctor? Maybe in the office?

Or am I over thinking this?

Comment: I think it means to exclude other contextually possible things. This should be the disambiguating function of は. That is to say that he specifically indicates that it is the doctor (and not anyone else that might be around that could have spoken) that said it.

Comment: What the hell is futsal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this には　is there because the verb is in passive form and it means "by". The sentence literally means

"I was told by the doctor to come play futsal already."

The following sentence is equivalent:

先生が「もうフットサルして来い」と言った！

The doctor said "Go play futsal already."

The に　comes whenever there is passive. For example "I was told by you" is

あなた**に**言われました。

The は in your sentence is the normal は used for emphasis.

Hope this helps.

Comment: に doesn't just appear because of a passive construction. As long as there is a relational/indirect object に is used to mark it. It should be a dative case marker.

Comment: @Flaw: Yes it doesn't only appear in sentences with passive form but in the question he wrote that he thought it meant "in the" which is not the case in the example.

Comment: Does には ever mean "in the [place]", or am I just completely wrong about that? For example, I thought 庭{にわ]には人{ひと}がいる was "there are people in the garden."

Comment: @DaveMG: You are not wrong at all, には can also mean "in". I meant to say that in this particular sentence it doesn't mean "in".

Comment: Picky correction to this answer: The doctor never said the words "come play futsal". He or she said to play futsal (フットサルして) and then come back (来い), or more naturally in English, to 'go' (and) play futsal. The wording "come" was only correct originally because it was an indirect quote / paraphrase.

Comment: @Hyperworm: I wondered about that. I didn't think the doctor was actually inviting my friend to go play in the hospital futsal league ;) . However, I wasn't sure enough that this was the come/go switch that often causes confusion, so I wasn't confident enough to translate it as "You should be off playing futsal", which is the sentiment I think it really has.

Comment: @DaveMG: btw, I read your profile: 頑張ってね、応援していますから。

Comment: @Hyperworm: Corrected the original question.

Comment: @Matt: Thanks. You'll be seeing *lots* of JLPT related questions from me in the next 3 weeks ;)

Comment: About に meaning place: There are three situations to differentiate: に as a destination, に as a stative location, and で as a location of an action. The first one is used only with verbs of motion: 家に行く. The second describes where something is, like 家にいる. The third (で) describes where someone is doing something: 家で食べる. It is ungrammatical to say 家に食べる, or 家でいる. Also, see the difference between the first and the third in 家で飛んでいる "They keep flying (while) inside the house" and 家に飛んでいる "They keep flying into the house". As others said, に in this case is another usage of に altogether, passive agent.